# Android -Handling "Previev" Intent from gmail

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail, preview

My app handles Intents ACTION_VIEW for type "text/plain" so i can open .txt file with it.
I don't have problems opening those files from any program, and from Gmail when i want to "OPEN" attachment from email everything works fine. 
   Problem appears when i want to "PREVIEW" attachment - gmail gives me different Intent. How to handle it?
I compared Intents from OPEN, and PREVIEW:

```
OPEN:
START OF INTENT!
action = android.intent.action.VIEW
getDataString = file:///mnt/sdcard/download/anime_rozne-1.txt
getData = file:///mnt/sdcard/download/anime_rozne-1.txt
getCategories = null
getComponent = {pl.my.package.deszyfrator/pl.my.package.deszyfrator.MainActivity}
getExtras = null
getPackage = null
getScheme = file
getType = text/plain
END OF INTENT!


PREVIEW:
START OF INTENT!
action = android.intent.action.VIEW
getDataString = content://gmail-ls/messages/my.email@0gmail.com/129/attachments/0.1/BEST/false
getData = content://gmail-ls/messages/my.email@gmail.com/129/attachments/0.1/BEST/false
getCategories = null
getComponent = {pl.my.package.deszyfrator/pl.my.package.deszyfrator.MainActivity}
getExtras = null
getPackage = null
getScheme = content
getType = text/plain
END OF INTENT!
```

What should i do with this?
`content://gmail-ls/messages/my.email@gmail.com/129/attachments/0.1/BEST/false`

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a specific Intent for Gmail. If you have access to the user's Gmail account then you could try and handle it. But my suggestion would be to add a `Data` tag to your `Intent Filter` so that you are only handling certain types of content.

More information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Basically your code would look something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" android:scheme="file" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

All of the valid fields for an `Intent Filter` can be found in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html).

Comment: Now i can't use option PREVIEW